# I want to change script links in wordpress header. Where are they defined?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, header, wordpress-theming

I've just installed an SSL certificate and I'm trying to make sure all the resources on the page are also called from a secure site so I don't get the "there is insecure content" error.

I looked through the code created by wordpress for one of my pages and found a link to:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js?ver=3.4
which I would like to change to https:// but I can't find where in the templates this is added.

If I'm in the editor for my template in the admin screens, is there a common page that builds the link to JS files? or is there a way for me to work back and figure out where this is being added so I can change the source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to search first in file header.php or footer.php (if the script is included directly with html).
Otherwise you should search in the file functions.php for some calls to this function :
wp_enqueue_script('...');

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a custom theme. Chances are it's in header.php. You may want to just edit it via FTP or SSH.